# API call limitation on my telegram bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

My telegram bot needs to send a message to all the users at the same time. However, Telegram claims a max of 30 calls/sec so it gets really slow. I am sure that there is a telegram bot which sends over 30 calls/sec. Is there a paid plan for this?

Comment: why not use multiple bots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Telegram don't provide paid plan at this time.

For sending massive amount of message, it is better to use channel, and ask users to join.

If you really want to send via PM, you can send 1,800 messages per minute, I think this limit is enough for most use case.